# Probability of arranging different books - High School Math

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

So I have 4  Math books, 1 Economic book and 1 Physics book. I want to arrange them on a straight line. What is the probability of the book arrangement so that there is no 3 or more Math books adjacent to each other? So MMEMMP is allowed but MMMEMP is not allowed.

The answer is 0.4.

Comment: Ignore the difference between the economics book and the physics book for the time being.  There are $\binom{6}{4}$ equally likely ways in which you place the math books on the line.  This can act as the denominator.  Then, counting the number of ways in which they can be split up will act as the numerator.  Since the problem is small, this can be done by brute force, maybe even in your head.  Note that with only two non-math books, you will have split the math books into either two or three clumps.  It could be MM-M-M, it could be M-MM-M, etc... on up to MM--MM and MM-MM-

Answer (score 0):

Total number of ways of arranging books= $6!/4!$=$30$
Now take all four math books as one object and permute in possible ways . It will be $3!$=$6$
Now take three Math book as one object and the other Math book should not be placed on either side of the three Math books. Therefore number of ways of arrangement = $2*3!$.
These cases need to be subtracted from the sample space .
You would be getting your answer as $12$.
Probability would be $12/30$ which is $0.4$.